# Why two same statements are returning different results with just parentheses wrapping one and not the other one?

Tags: javascript

Why two same statements are returning different results with just parentheses wrapping one and not the other one?

```
function foo(bar){
    return !bar;
}(false) ? false : true; // returns true
```

---

```
(function foo(bar){
    return !bar;
}(false) ? false : true); // returns false! why?!
```

Comment: The first snippet is evaluated as *function declaration* followed by the conditional operator. The second one is evaluated as conditional operator where the condition is a *function expression* which gets called immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function foo(bar){
    return !bar;
}
(false) ? false : true
```

is like saying:

```
if(false){
   //false
} else {
   //true
}
```

your function is not called, and your condition is `false`, meaning it returns the second statement (which has `//true`).

---

the second is VERY different

```
(function foo(bar){
    return !bar;
}
(false) ? false : true)
```

is like this:

```
function foo(bar){
    return !bar;
}

var temp = foo(false)

if(temp){
    //false
} else {
    //true
}
```

you are technically creating a <s>self-executing function</s> [immediately invoked function expressions (IFFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) with `false` as a parameter. whatever it returns is subject to the condition. so:

- you passed `false` as parameter
- the function returns an inversion, which is `true`
- the return is evaluated, and since the return is `true`, it executes the first statement of your condition (which has `//false`)

---

<s>self-executing functions</s> [immediately invoked function expressions (IFFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) commonly have these forms, and are commonly used to form **closures** (which is out of the scope of this question)

```
var result = (function(innerParam){
    //function body
}(passedParam));

and

//this form commonly seen in jQuery plugins
var result = (function(innerParam){
    //function body
})(passedParam);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function foo(bar)
{
    alert('fun 1 executed');
    return !bar;
}
(false) ? false : true; // returns true
```

And this:

```
(function foo(bar)
{
    alert('fun 2 executed');
    return !bar;
}
(false) ? false : true);
```

Notice that in case 1 the function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/JPv3j/1/

But anyway it's a weird construct that you shouldn't probably use in the first place if it has the possibility to be misinterpreted.

Comment: You don't have to run codes like this. Just use [console](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html)

Comment: I'm very aware of console. I just find jsfiddle.net convenient to show other people something.

Comment: _"It doesn't for me."_ - That's because in your fiddle both cases are function expressions. Judging from the previous comment it looks like the OP is running each block in the console exactly as is (rather than assigning them to something), which means the first block consists of a function statement followed by a separate ternary conditional expression.

Comment: @nnnnnn You're probably right. I wonder why the OP is doing it that way. Anyway, there have been some good answers here, so I guess the mystery is solved.